# Как перевести ip адрес в двоичную систему?

Tags: алгоритм

Помогите понять, каким образом происходит преобразование. Нужна схема, по которой происходит преобразование.

Comment: Хм... По байту на секцию в случае IPv4 и по два байта в случае IPv6?

Comment: И в случае IPv6 заполнение нулями области между двумя подряд идущими двоеточиями.

Answer (score 2):

```
64.233.187.99 => 64*2^24 + 233*2^16 + 187*2^8 + 99 = 1089059683

1089059683 => 1000000111010011011101101100011
```

Для перевода чисел из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную используют так называемый "алгоритм замещения", состоящий из следующей последовательности действий:

1. Делим десятичное число А на 2. Частное Q запоминаем для следующего шага, а остаток a записываем как младший бит двоичного числа.
2. Если частное q не равно 0, принимаем его за новое делимое и повторяем процедуру, описанную в шаге 1. Каждый новый остаток (0 или 1) записывается в разряды двоичного числа в направлении от младшего бита к старшему.
3. Алгоритм продолжается до тех пор, пока в результате выполнения шагов 1 и 2 не получится частное Q = 0 и остаток a = 1.

[Источник](http://vestikinc.narod.ru/AB/dec_bin_tr.htm)

Comment: такая вот проблемка:
имеется ip 5.100.192.0/21
после преобразования он должен выглядеть
000001010110010011000
а он выглядит 
101011001001100000000000000
с последними нулями понятно. а вот откуда должны появится первые нули?

Comment: Добавил алгоритм

Answer (score 0):

Первые нули добавляются к числу, чтобы образовать октет. Так как IPv4 адрес состоит из 4-х октетов. Длина IPv4 адреса должна быть 32 бита. Если число не использует все 8 битов, то добавляется необходимое количество нулей впереди, вне зависимости, в каком октете расположено данное число.